# How does electric potential energy affect mass?

Tags: mass-energy

I have three questions about weights of electrically charged balloons, the last one is the main question.

Question 1:

Let's say we have two seesaws, each seesaw has a positive charged balloon on the left, and a negatively charged balloon on the right. Both seesaws are in balance, when they are far from each other.

If we bring the seesaws close to each other, so that particularly the positive balloons are close to each other, then we are increasing the mass-energy of the system of the two positive balloons. Said system is supported by the two ends of the two seesaws.

Do the seesaws go off-balance because the system consisting of the two positive balloons weighs more than the system consisting of the two negative balloons?

Question 2:

Let's say we have one seesaw, which has a positive charged balloon on the left, and a negatively charged balloon on the right. The seesaw is in balance.

If we bring a positive charge close to the positive balloon, then we are increasing the mass-energy of the system of the two positive things. Said system is partly supported by one end of the seesaw. Does this seesaw go off-balance when a positive charge is brought close to the positive balloon?

Question 3:

Same as question 2, but we keep bringing positive charges near the seesaw, so that the positive charges form a sphere around the seesaw. Is the seesaw off-balance when there is an uniformly charged sphere around the seesaw?